# How can I create a jsk file from a pepk file?

Tags: android, keystore

I left my .jsk file in my other computer, now I only have a .pepk (Keystore) file. Is there a way to get the jsk file back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the .jsk file, now. 
One way could be to generate a new one.
Another obvious way could be to get it back from the other computer, when you can.
But if right now you want to update an app that is already on the Google play console-then you need to get that .jsk file back. There are things that you can do with that .pepk file without having the .jsk file , see here [https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing]. I just dont think getting back that .jsk file is one of them.